# How to Save an asp.net webpage to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, pdf

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to Convert html web-page to image format in ASP.net web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280817/how-to-convert-html-web-page-to-image-format-in-asp-net-web-application)
>   [ASP.NET page to image or pdf.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084321/asp-net-page-to-image-or-pdf)

Hi,

I have an aspx webpage. Once that page is rendered, with a button click how can I export it to PDF? What is the process? Do I need an external third party tool to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280817/how-to-convert-html-web-page-to-image-format-in-asp-net-web-application  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084321/asp-net-page-to-image-or-pdf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654750/save-my-asp-net-mvc-page-as-pdf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826441/convert-asp-net-page-into-byte

Answer (score 1):

We've had good luck using the iTextSharp library. It's easy to use and the price is right.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Answer (score 1):

There are several third party libraries that support this. We have one that provides perfect fidelity and has been optimised for use on the server. [Have a look at this blog post](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/08/convert-sharepoint-html-pages-to-pdf.html).